# Как произвести расшифровку с помощью алгоритма RSA?

Tags: алгоритм, rsa

Как произвести расшифрование, используя следующее:

Для вычисления ^   необходимо использовать следующий алгоритм:

1. Шаг 1: с = 1, n’ = 0.
2. Шаг 2: увеличение n’ на 1.
3. Шаг 3: =(∗)  .
4. Шаг 4: если n’ <n, то возвратиться к шагу 2, иначе c содержит окончательный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы википедию, что ли открыли.
Пользователь А зашифровывает данные m на открытом ключе `(e,n)`. Т.е. `m^e mod n = c` и это зашифрованное c отправляем пользователю В.
Пользователь B расшифровывает данные каким образом?
`с^d mod n`, где `с` - пришедшее сообщение зашифрованное, `(d,n)` закрытый ключ, который пользователь B знает и на выходе мы получаем изначальное сообщение `m`.
Это вкратце без подробностей генерации ключей и проч.